# How to get the clients external ip, im using Gcloud/kubernetes

Tags: networking, docker, containers, kubernetes, gcloud

i recently started working with kubernetes on gcloud, its been pretty smooth so far, but i cant seem to get the **clients/user external ip address** on my app using wildfly(jsf) any ideas would be appreciated!
I expose my pod using the following command:

`kubectl expose rc modcluster-replication-controller --name=modcluster  --type="LoadBalancer"`

- 1 pod running wildfly standalone mode
- 1 pod running mod-cluster
- 1 pod running postgres
- 1 rc running mod-cluster-replication controler
- 1 expose rc mod-cluster-replication controler port 80
- 1 gcloud loadbalancer

***Im using kubernetes, gcloud, modcluster, wildfly*** based off [Ticket-monster Kubernetes](https://github.com/rafabene/devops-demo/tree/master/kubernetes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion (if your application is HTTP/HTTPs on ports 80/443) is to
take advantage of the Ingress controller which basically expose the
services as an HTTP/HTTPs load balancer that injects the X-Forwarded-For in the packets.

This will reveal the source/client's IP address. Please follow the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#before_you_begin)
Details on the X-Forwarded-For field are available [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#components)

Sample call that I just tested with that tutorial:
LB IP: 130.211.10.191

Tcpdump inside the container:

`$ tcpdump  -n -l -w - | strings`

```
Output:
Host: 130.211.10.191
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept:
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 7978.74.0) AppleWebKit/537.36
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.103 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
If-None-Match: "574da256-264"
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 31 May 2016 14:40:22 GMT
X-Cloud-Trace-Context:
6b36a7d93d60dc6921417796255466d5/14093000126457324029
Via: 1.1 google
X-Forwarded-For: 81.47.XXX.XXX, 130.211.10.191    # the IP starting with
81. is my local IP
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
Connection: Keep-Alive
JxHTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
```

Comment: Gow i'd been all over the place, google, stackoverflow, gcloud docs, made some changes to fit apache and it worked, thanks you very much, read about **ingress** but  wasnt sure how it worked, quick question why is the ip created in that range of 130...?

Comment: @PaulMB - no particular reason. In my case it was the ip address that was automatically assigned to my Google HTTP/S LB. I am happy my solution worked out for you. Please mark the answer as "accepted". Good luck with Kubernetes - it's an awesome product!

Answer (score 0):

k8s version 1.7 (just tested in 1.7.2) makes this a breeze. Just use spec:externalTrafficPolicy:Local in your LoadBalancer Service. It will serve port 80 and 443 without any issue. For instance:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myservice
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
    name: http
  - port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 443
    name: https
  selector:
    app: myapp
    role: myrole
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 104.196.208.195
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kubectl describe svc servicename | grep 'LoadBalancer Ingress'
```